# UI Busy Animation Etiquette

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

The problem:  normally a method executes so quickly that you see the busy animation flash up on the UI, it is so fast it looks like a bit of a glitch. There are scenarios where it can also take a long time to execute.

I'm tempted to make the UI show at least 1 complete animation of the busy spinner regardless of how quickly the method executes (on a background worker)...I guess this is a question of etiquette - should a programmer create code which forces the user to wait a small amount of time. Surely otherwise the brief flashes on the screen will be perceived as bugs/poor software?

Comment: This is more of a generic process question, it may be better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ rather than SO which is usually more for specific technical issues or code problems

Comment: If it is on a background worker then why do you need a busy indicator.  If it executes in a flash then why the overhead of a background worker.   Really, you think a user wants to see a full cycle of the busy indicator.   I think excessive use of busy indicators will be perceived as poor software.

Comment: I expect 90% of cases it doesn't *need* to be on a background worker, but to ensure responsiveness in the UI 100% of the time i have done this. The method being called on the background worker is making service calls over the network, the amount of time it takes is variable/unpredictable at best. If there is no notification that it is doing something in a long running process wont they assume its stopped working and call support?

Comment: Notification does not need to be a busy indicator.  My opinion is a busy indicator is the wrong notification for background worker.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a design question. Why don't you apply a fade-in fade-out on your busy indicator. This way, the indicator would not flash if it shows up for a short period of time. I would strongly discourage forcing the user to see a busy indicator for longer than he needs to